Intel Celeron Dummy Sound Output Ubuntu fix?
Good Day
Can somebody please assist me with fixing dummy output sound, I use a Proline Proline V146GNS Intel Celeron, just installed Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. when I try fix via command by installing ALSA, Pulse Audio or snd, I get this:
proline@proline-V146GNS:~$ systemctl status alsa
Unit alsa.service could not be found.
proline@proline-V146GNS:~$ systemctl status pulseaudio
Unit pulseaudio.service could not be found.
proline@proline-V146GNS:~$ systemctl status snd
Unit snd.service could not be found.
proline@proline-V146GNS:~$ systemctl --version
systemd 249 (249.11-0ubuntu3.12)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY -P11KIT -QRENCODE +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified

Can someone please tell me how to rectify this, I need the sound.

You didn't mention what Ubuntu product (Server? Desktop?), and gave no clues as to your hardware either..  I'd have explored what audio/sound hardware was detected first by the linux kernel (eg. sudo lshw -C sound for example)

Hi, sorry about that, seems like I have an issue with pulse audio. check this out: proline@proline-V146GNS:~$ inxi -Axx
Audio:
Device-1: Intel Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio
driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:0e.0 chip-ID: 8086:3198
Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.5.0-28-generic running: yes
Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: no
Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes

proline@proline-V146GNS:~$ pulseaudio -D
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
proline@proline-V146GNS:~$ systemctl --user status pulseaudio
○ pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor >
Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: ○ pulseaudio.socket
